# How to save json dumps of responses in python google api client?

Tags: python, google-api

In the python google api documentation regarding [mocks](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/main/docs/mocks.md) it is stated:

> As you develop and test your application, it is a good idea to save actual API responses in files like books-discovery.json or books-android.json for use in testing.

Where do I get these json from? In particular the response to mock the build() command.

EDIT:

The class I want to test, calendar.py:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build


class Calendar:
    def __init__(self, credentials_file, calendar_id) -> None:
        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
            credentials_file, scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"]
        )
        self.service = build("calendar", "v3", credentials=credentials)
        self._id = calendar_id
```

How to retrive the json response of build to save it in `calendar-discovery.json`?

Modified class to simplify mocking

```
import google_auth_httplib2
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import build_http

class Calendar:
    def __init__(self, credentials_file, calendar_id) -> None:
        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
            credentials_file, scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"]
        )
        http = google_auth_httplib2.AuthorizedHttp(credentials, http=build_http())
        self.service = build("calendar", "v3", http=http)
        self._id = calendar_id
```

The test:

```
def test_calendar_initialization(mocker):
    mock = mocker.patch("meal_planner.calendar.build_http")
    mock.return_value = HttpMock("calendar-discovery.json", {"status": 200})

    calendar = Calendar(credentials_file="credential.json", calendar_id="id")
```

Comment: Most Google APIs return JSON.  Do you have an example?

Comment: I don't see where you are making any requests here.

Comment: wild guess but try checking this sample https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/installed-py  check the .dat.

Comment: Going directly to the source: https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/mocks.html. How do you generate `books-discovery.json`? They only say `books_discovery = # Saved data from a build response`

Answer (score 0):

1. List all the discovery APIs: https://discovery.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis
2. Search for `"name": "calendar"`
3. Look for `"discoveryRestUrl": "https://calendar-json.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v3"`
4. Get the calendar discovery document

   ```sh
   curl https://calendar-json.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v3 > calendar-discovery.json`
   ```

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/discovery